# Increase the maximum length for questions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, character-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serverfault cut off/truncated on long post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/serverfault-cut-off-truncated-on-long-post)

There's [a question of some importance to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246540/apache-tomcat-error-wrong-pages-being-delivered) on SO in which I've cronicled the various failed attempts to solve a problem. The last few episodes of this ongoing story are truncated mid-word. Could the question length limit please be removed or adjusted?

Answer (score 0):

See this:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12988/serverfault-cut-off-truncated-on-long-post

I fixed your question.